# awk code to filter sequences below 80 bp and 80% coverage

Tags: awk

I want to filter my table based on those sequences that have at least 80 base pair (end-begin+1 >= 80) which spans over 80% of their total length (base pairs left should be =< 20% of the total length: (end-begin+1) + left = total length)

```
| query sequence | begin | end | (left)|
| -------------- | ------| --- | ----- |
| D1             | 1     | 330 | (1939)|
| D2             | 2180  | 2269| (0)   |
| D3             | 4     | 168 | (0)   |
| D4             | 1     | 1610| (0)   |
| D5             | 1     | 402 | (84)  |
| D6             | 1     | 58  | (0)   |
| D7             | 1     | 79  | (0)   |
| D8             | 4     | 167 | (437) |
| D9             |310    | 478 | (214) |
| D10            |1      | 227 | (234) |
| D11            |2      | 604 | (141) |
```

that is my awk code:

```
awk '{print $0, $7-$6+1, $7+$8, ($7-$6+1)/($7+$8)}' | awk '$18 >= 0.8 {print $0}'
```

however there are sequences that are not filtered according to the minimum 80 base pair nor the 80% of the total length rule, where am I wrong?

the expected output:

```
| query sequence | begin | end | (left)|
| -------------- | ------| --- | ----- |
| D2             | 2180  | 2269| (0)   |
| D3             | 4     | 168 | (0)   |
| D4             | 1     | 1610| (0)   |
| D5             | 1     | 402 | (84)  |
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do add samples of input and expected output in text form in your question so that we could test our code in samples, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I added the table to the main question.

Comment: Please, post a proper exhaustive testable sample with the expected output. Now we get to read "it didn't work" comments between solutions. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to post a proper table other than typing every single column one by one which is not really feasible for me. please understand my tables are made of thousands columns, if there is a simple way of putting it in text format, do let me know, thanks.

Comment: Don;t post graphical representations of data in  your question, post the actual text files. We can't copy/paste a picture or other such representation of your data to test with it. You're getting answers that don't do what you want because you haven't provided sample input/output that we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with.

Comment: We don't need or want the thousands of columns, we need the columns and records that are needed to solve the problem, like this you posted as a comment: `2  61  (0)`. We also need the expected output for the given sample. When posting data, edit it to the original question as text, use four spaces before each data record for proper markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column `$8` `(left)` has parentheses around the numbers, therefore `awk` fails to interpret `$8` as a number and uses `0` instead. Example: `awk '{print $1+2}' <<< '(3)'` prints `2` instead of `5`.

You can extract the number inside the parentheses into a variable using `left=$8; gsub(/[()]/,"",left)`.

By the way: No need for 2 `awk` scripts. You can do everything in one script:

```
awk '{left=$8; gsub(/[()]/,"",left); bp=$7-$6+1; tl=bp+left} bp>=80 && bp>0.8*tl'
```

Comment: I tried it: `cat input.tsv | awk '{l=$1; gsub(/[()]/,"",l); bp=$7-$6+1; tl=bp+l} bp>=80 && l<=0.2*tl' > output.len80` it didn't work for me, I lost more than 90% of the input data, incorrectly

Comment: Oops, I used `l=$1` from my minimal example when I should have used `$8` for the actual script. I updated the answer. If there are still problems, edit your question with a minimal example (input file and expected output) so that I can test this script myself.

Comment: now everything is ok with the length, however the 80% of the total length is still not filtered completely, e.g. 1    81 (1158), 1   227  (234), 310   478  (214)

Comment: Never use a variable named `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` (indistinguishable in some fonts) and so obfuscates your code. In `bp=$7-$6+1; tl=bp+l`, for example, it's extremely hard to tell what's a `l` and what's a `1`.

Comment: @xyz0o I implemented the check `left<=0.2*tl` just as you described. Quote *"**left** should be =< 20% of the total length"*. But looking at your expected output, it seems like you might wanted `bp>0.8*tl` instead, even though that also prints `D5`, which is not listed in you expected output. Anyways, your original problem seems to be solved. Feel free to alter the filter condition in this script according to your needs. I don't see a point in asking you to clarify/correct your filter rules when you could write them yourself in less time.

Answer (score 0):

You might set custom field separator to get just numbers in `$8` (and other columns) rather than digits inside `(` and `)`, i.e. replace

```
awk '{print $0, $7-$6+1, $7+$8, ($7-$6+1)/($7+$8)}'
```

using

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[)[:space:](]+"}{print $0, $7-$6+1, $7+$8, ($7-$6+1)/($7+$8)}'
```

Explanation: treat any combination of `)` whitespace `(` as field separator (`FS`). Not tested due to lack of sample input as text. If you want to know more about `FS` read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: this works, yet with errors, e.g.  `2       61      (0)` : the length is clearly less than 80. my own piece of code is `cat input.tsv | sed 's/[()]//g' | awk '{print $0, $7-$6+1, $7+$8, ($7-$6+1)/($7+$8)}' | awk '$18 >= 0.8 {print $0}' > output` which has the same problem.

Comment: @xyz0o you never need sed or cat when using awk, nor do you need to pipe calls to awk to each other. Use the script that's posted, don't try to modify it and then complain that the modified version doesn't work.

Comment: please re-read the comment sir, it says "my own piece of code has the same problem" which means I have tried the "unmodified" code and mine. Also if you read the answer carefully: `awk 'BEGIN{FS="[)[:space:](]+"}{print $0, $7-$6+1, $7+$8, ($7-$6+1)/($7+$8)}` is not the full code, it doesn't take into account the 80% of the total length. @Ed Morton

Comment: I see, I didn't understand that's what you meant when I read your comment. Adding your own code with a cat + sed + multiple awks and pipelines just cluttered up your comment and made it harder to understand, all you had to say was that the code in the answer had specific errors.